# Отследить, когда в django выполняется запрос к бд

Tags: django, postgresql

к примеру выполняется код

```
for event in Event.objects.all():
    print(event.user.username)
```

или

```
for event in User.objects.last().events.all():
    print(event.name)
```

где

```
class Event(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='events')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=28)
```

Как узнать, сколько запросов было произведено к бд?
Как можно отследить когда в django выполняется запрос к бд? Есть ли сигнал отвечающий за это? Может быть будет проще отслеживать это в самой бд(Postgresql), если да, то как?

Comment: [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar)

Comment: Попробуйте анализ логов на стороне `pg` утилитой `pgbadger`